# Symfony: Overload helpers?

Tags: html, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'd like to overload the `include_http_metas()` helper (from the `AssetHelper` class) in order to make it HTML5 compliant.

Any ideas?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the AssetHelper.php file (there is no class AssetHelper class at all) in the lib/helper directory of your app, and make your changes in the copy.

Source : http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer (§ Adding your own helpers)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do but as include_http_metas() calls sfContext::getInstance()->getResponse()->getHttpMetas() you could use your own response class (defined in your factories.yml config) and use your own getHttpMetas() there.